# Blender - show edges angles “direction”

Tags: edges

I'm working on a papercraft project on Pepakura. 
Valley folds show in light blue and Montain Folds in dark blue in this software.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to show the angle of the folding edges directly on Blender ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please edit "I'm working on a papercraft project...in dark blue" into two sentences. I had to re-read that nearly 10 times before I concluded that light folds are called "Pepakura and Valley" and dark folds are called "Montain"

Answer (score 5):

Closest thing I know in Blender is using *Mesh Analysis* from the *Properties Side Bar*.

Enter *Edit Mode* on a mesh object, turn on *Mesh Analysis*, set it to *Sharp* and adjust the angles as desired.

[image]

Have in mind that it can't highlight single edges as illustrated, only face angles. Not sure if it can both show concave and convex edges at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

In edit mode hit "N" and look for the Mesh Display tab.

[image]